# Is it possible to call a general shared library in a JNI library under Android?

Tags: android, c++, shared-libraries

I have a dynamic linked library (.so) built for general Linux platforms usage (x86, armv7a), now I'm going to port the library for Android usage.

What I expect is to use ***dlopen*** in the JNI library's CPP code to access the other library which is not in JNI form. So that I only need to develop a few JNI functions to bridge the exported functions of the original library.

This is all for avoid rebuilding whole codes of the original library. There are a large number of source files and the structure is very complicated. Otherwise I have to rewrite the makefile for NDK building for them.

To try this concept, I almost progress to the last step.

First, I put the original library and JNI library together in location ***/data/data/com.example.myapp/lib*** in the device's root file system (I use the emulator in Android Studio, the tool will copy .so files in project's ***lib*** folder automatically in installation).

The following I use ***adt*** to login the android's shell and I issue `file` command to list the files in the ***lib*** directory

```
generic_x86_arm:/data/data/com.example.myapp/lib # file *
libSmart.so: ELF shared object, 32-bit LSB 386, BuildID=179c89de2ebe921fe1b9be6e78e83148f3781568, stripped
libmain.so:  ELF shared object, 32-bit LSB 386, for Android 16, built by NDK r21e (7075529), BuildID=6b395607222185aac9c163dc205b26add1ab55c4, stripped
```

- libSmart.so: The original library I built for general Linux platforms
- libmain.so: The JNI library which will called by JAVA of android activity.

I can open libSmart.so by `fopen()`, but can't open it by `dlopen()` which it returns NULL.

Is there some constraints to do these? Or is any libraries used in Android (even not directly called by JAVA) must be built with JNI?

Comment: Use [JNA](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/blob/master/www/AndroidDevelopmentEnvironment.md) (JNI is **old**).

Comment: Anything in logcat? Does it make a difference if you actually bundle the library with your APK instead? Have you tried linking libmain against libSmart instead of trying to use dlopen?